# Unable to validate data - MVC Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, machinekey

I have this MVC website that has been working for about 3 weeks. Suddenly I started getting

> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

whenever connecting to the website. My host sent me the dump file and it said

> Event code: 3012  Event message: An error occurred processing a web or
>   script resource request. The resource identifier failed to decrypt.
>
> Exception type: HttpException  Exception message: Unable to validate
>   data. at
>   System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean
>   fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length,
>   Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean useLegacyMode, IVType ivType,
>   Boolean signData) at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptString(String s,
>   Purpose purpose) at
>   System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   context, VirtualFileReader fileReader, Action`2 logAction, Boolean
>   validatePath)

After some research I added

machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="3DES" decryption="3DES"

to the web.config file based off my research online but still no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post the code that's throwing the error?

Comment: From the stacktrace of the exception I can see this: `System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptString`. This is classic WebForms controls.  You should absolutely not be using any classic WebForms stuff in an ASP.NET MVC application. Classic ASP.NET WebForms and MVC have completely different lifecycles and rely on different notions. Once you start mixing them in the same application you are unleashing HELL. Search for `runat="server"` in your MVC application and get rid of it as soon as possible.

Comment: @Ihan16 I am not sure where exactly the error is being thrown. Locally it works fine but when I copy to the host it fails after about an hour or so

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I just did a search for runat and runat="server" in the entire solution but I could not find anywhere it is being used

Comment: Has your host updated the .NET framework?  Do you use AntiForgeryTokens() in your app?

Comment: @Tommy Yeah the host mentioned keeping the .NET framework up to date. Didn't bother to use any AntiForgeryTokens just yet.

Comment: I would recommend trying to generate your own key instead of AutoGenerate, maybe they've load balanced or changed something on their config - http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey